# TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular11

Recently upgrading my app to Angular 11. Jest has been set up as the default testing framework. Running npm test results in the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

      20 | @Component({
      21 |     selector: 'app-bx-input-textbox',
    > 22 |     template: require('./bx-input-textbox.component.html'),
         |               ^
      23 |     styles: [String(require('./bx-input-textbox.component.scss'))],
      24 |     providers: [
      25 |         {

      at ScriptTransformer._getTransformer (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:357:15)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:419:28)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:523:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at src/app/core/components/bx-input-textbox/bx-input-textbox.component.ts:22:15
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/components/bx-input-textbox/bx-input-textbox.component.ts:38:1)
```

// jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform",
    "\\.(ts|js)$": ['ts-jest']
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  globals: {    
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: {
        // allow js in typescript
        allowJs: true,
      },
    },
  },
  // If you need to test a specifc file just include it here
  //testMatch: ['**/repository.jobs.spec.ts'],
  testMatch: []
};
```

Package versions
"@angular-builders/jest": "12.1.0",
"@types/jest": "24.9.1",
"ts-jest": "26.0.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",

I have tried different configurations with the jest.config.js file but not able to resolve this error. Any pointers to resolve this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 90):

your `ts-jest` version must match the `jest` version.

Comment: @slideshowp2 actually this does provide an answer to the question and even fixes the issue. The OP has `ts-jest@26.0.0` while using `jest@24.9.0` which leads to the error presented.

Comment: It worked, in my case I tried with `"jest": "^27.1.3"` and `"ts-jest": "^27.1.3"`

Comment: It is the second time I came across this answer and a second time it solved my issue. cheers :)

Answer (score 43):

Upgraded **jest** and **ts-jest** to v27 to fix this issue

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue for me.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts I had the same issue. See my answer below...

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts it seems that upgrade and [clear jest cache](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/2612#issuecomment-848587164) has been working for some.

Answer (score 8):

Met the same issue with "ts-jest": "^27.0.5" and fixed by revert to "ts-jest": "^26.4.2"

Comment: worked for angular 11 and node v16

Answer (score 7):

You may also need to upgrade `jest-cli`, along with `jest` & `ts-jest`.

Comment: I don't have `jest-cli` installed, unfortunately.

Comment: you might have it implicitly installed. Make sure that the version lines up using `npm ls jest-cli `

Answer (score 4):

If your `ts-jest` version is `27.x.x`, you have to install a matching `jest` version of `27....`. Simply install by

```
npm install -D jest@27
```

to get the latest version from `jest 27`

Answer (score 3):

Wiping node modules and .jest folder finally got rid of this.

```
rm -rf ./node_modules && rm -rf .jest && yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that the versions of jest and ts-jest match.

What is really necessary is for the version to be compatible.

When I faced this issue I was using jest@^28.1.1 and to your surprise does not exist version 28.1.1 for ts-jest.

I end up upgrading ts-jest for the closest one I found. For me, I end up with the following versions

```
jest@^28.1.1
ts-ject@28.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing (using this [troubleshooting guide](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typeerror-jest-a-transform-must-export-a-process-function) as a starting point)

Got my `ts-jest`, `jest`, and `@types/jest` all on the same version number (used whatever was the lowest common denominator).

Was able to find the lowest one by running:

```
npm list jest --depth=0
npm list ts-jest --depth=0
```

Installed the lowest common denominator version that matched across the dependencies:

```
yarn add -D ts-jest@<version> jest@<version> @types/jest<version>
```

In my case this ended up being `29.1.0`:

```
yarn add -D ts-jest@29.1.0 jest@29.1.0 @types/jest@29.1.0
```

Then I removed `react-scripts`, and reinstalled it.

```
yarn remove react-scripts
yarn add -D react-scripts
```

Then that error went away. :)