# ReferenceError: expect is not defined when using @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm learning to write a test for my react typescript app and come across this problem. I tried to use many different methods I found on internet but nothing work, the error is

```
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: expect is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/extend-expect.js:7:1)

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect.js:2:1)
```

This is my App.test.tsx file. Where error occur.

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import {render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
test('renders learn react link',async () => {
    let screen = render(<App></App>);
     expect(screen.getByText(/Hello/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

And these are my jest.config.js and bebel.config.js file (Not sure if this matter)

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)",
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
  },
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
};
```

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  const presets = [
      '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-flow'
  ];
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
  ];
  api.cache(false);
  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/122#issuecomment-650520461.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete `node_modules` directory and do `npm install`

also replace the `"setupFiles"` with `setupFilesAfterEnv` in `jest.config.js` like following

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
  './setupTests.js',
],
```

try this in `App.test.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import {render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen} from '@testing-library/react'

test('renders learn react link',async () => {
    let screen = render(<App/>);
     expect(screen.getByText(/Hello/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Comment: Tried it, and I got this error instead.
TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

Comment: can you attach the image of error in question ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356503/typeerror-jest-a-transform-must-export-a-process-function

Comment: [https://imgur.com/uZtAsid](https://imgur.com/uZtAsid)

Comment: `ts-jest`  is required in your code? try after removing it.

Comment: It's work now after removing ts-jest, thanks a lot.